# Gethashcode() function

Tags: c#, reference, equals, gethashcode

Why aren't C1 and c2 have the same hashcode ? 
the code doesn't get to "Same".... ( i=0 in both classes)

```
class myclass
{
    public static int i;

    static void Main()
    {
        myclass c1 = new myclass();
        myclass c2 = new myclass();

        if (c1.GetHashCode() == c2.GetHashCode())
            Console.Write("Same");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant programming language.

Comment: I assume whatever language this is does the same thing as Java when you don't override Object's hashCode(), and just returns the address of the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implementation of `GetHashCode()` is based on the reference, not the fields of the object.

If you want them to be the same, you need to override `GetHashCode()`, so it is based on your field (and then you should remember to override `Equals()` also).

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating *different instances* of the same class. Each instance of a class has its own hashcode, and the hashcode is used to identify an object in your program's memory, even if they both share the same field values.

If you did this, however, it'll write "Same", because you're just creating two variables that point to the same object (i.e. you're passing the reference of `c1` to the object to `c2`):

```
    myclass c1 = new myclass();
    myclass c2 = c1;

    if (c1.GetHashCode() == c2.GetHashCode())
        Console.Write("Same");
```

Of course, I don't think this is what you're looking to achieve.